# JPanel not showing background image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

It is very simple program and i have tried my best but the JPanel doesn't come up with a background image. I just want a simple background image on my panel.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

class PanelEx extends JPanel
{
    BufferedImage img;

    PanelEx()
    {
        try
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Pictures/s_4261.jpg"));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void printComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(img,0,0,null);
    }
}

class JPanelEx2 extends JFrame
{
    PanelEx pe;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new JPanelEx2();
    }

    JPanelEx2()
    {
        pe = new PanelEx();

        add(pe);
        setTitle("JPanel Title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(320,240);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
public void printComponent(Graphics g) {
```

with

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks, any suggestion how to make it stretchy along with the frame size?

Comment: @ZakiMohammed Try this: `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);`

Comment: Cool! Thanks @LuxxMiner

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a JPanel. Just use a JLabel with an Icon then you don't need custom code.

See Background Panel for more information as well as a solution that will paint the image on a JPanel with 3 different painting options:

1. scaled
2. tiled
3. actual